# What's the difference between game development and business development?

Tags: language-agnostic

Like most developers, I'm a business developer, which in essence consists of slapping a UI onto some back-end data store. (We all know there's a lot more to it than that, but that's usually what it boils down to.)

I understand that game development is very different from business development, but I'm having a hard time explaining it to a friend of mine. I was hoping the SO community could help me out here.

To me, modern game developers deal a lot with manipulating 3-dimensional graphics. In gaming code (and I'm guessing here), you're assembling polygons (or something like that), rotating 'em, etc. This involves a different way of thinking from manipulating relational data (for instance). I don't know, really. I just know it's different.

**EDIT:**

I should stress that by "development" I mean "programming," not all of the aspects that go into creating a game or piece of business software. I'm sorry I didn't make that clear originally.

Thanks!

Comment: What about system development? Device software, defence and transport systems - there is more to software than games and enterprise!

Comment: True! But that's not what my friend wanted to know. He asked me whether I could code a game, and I said that was a very different kind of dev from what I know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm in game development but came from business development long ago. Game development is very rigorous in mathematics if you work on the physics or graphics side. Even AI can need quite a bit of mathematics for the low-level stuff. The hardware usually takes care of a lot of the polygon manipulation math as far as drawing on the screen goes. There is also a lot of involvement with generating the in-game data with (often) many tools that are run in a pre-processing step, and that too can be math-intensive if you are generating visibility data.

Comment: It's the math that makes game development different, to my mind. People assume that computer programming in general involves math, but as a business developer I rarely use anything beyond extremely simple math, except for some occasional statistics. Most people are shocked to hear it.

Comment: Yep, the only math I dealt with in business development was with dollars and cents, maybe the occasional percentage.

Answer (score 9):

In terms of programming domains, amongst other things, we deal with:

- Graphics programming (including shader development)
- Animation
- Physics simulation
- AI and gameplay
- Audio
- Networking (typically fairly low-level stuff)

Some of these involve pretty serious maths and algorithms knowledge.  On top of all that, we face extremely tough speed constraints, and typically have to be very careful with memory usage too.  We face constantly changing hardware, and since we're trying to push hardware to the limit, this can be pretty tough - you can't just abstract it away.  Most game development is still quite low-level C++ work.  We probably deal with databases less than most other programmers nowadays (although online games are changing this)!

Programmers are often the minority on modern game projects: it's all about content creation (animation, modelling, texturing, audio and design).  This means many game programmers are dedicated to making the content creation process efficient, rather than working on the game code itself.  This work may have more relaxed speed and memory constraints, although it does have to deal with massive data sets.

Making the game 'fun' is one of the hardest things to do - in business terminology, it "means extremely unstable requirements" as the designers constantly change their mind about how things should work, to chase down that elusive fun factor.

Finally, games are generally a ship-once, no chance to fix stuff kind of deal.  This actually means there's very little code maintenance involved, so traditionally there may have been less attention paid to code quality issues.  This is changing now with the growth in post-launch content addition, online gaming and the sheer size of modern projects.

Overall it's an incredibly exciting field to be in, the downside is that it's often less well paid (because it's a very tough business financially for developers, and because it's popular, there's always a fresh supply of people looking for jobs).

Answer (score 6):

Just some random thoughts about what is different in game development. Note that there might be some sarcasm in it, though I tried to suppress the urge.

- Unless you're a lucky employee of one of those new-style studios (like Eidos Montreal or Blizzard), there is always a deadline to fear that is much too short. In business programming, you mostly make the deadline up for yourself.
- A business application serves some specific need. A game's intent is to entertain people. You can't really predict if a game will fail until it's out.
- Performance is essential, in every aspect of the game. Writing code that is good to maintain is second priority. In business programming, good code that works is top priority.
- For a business application, a shiny UI is a bonus. For a game, it is a must.
- Debugging games is much harder, because there is always some hardware dependence which results in bugs that can only be reproduced on some machines, none of which is in your company. And a game sucks up much more performance than a typical business application.
- You have people dedicated to creating the art, story, music, sound, background and design, none of which necessarily needs programming knowledge (scripting is a little different), i.e. you have a lot of content which is what the users (players) will see. Nobody cares about how good your code is, unless performance is bad or there are bugs. The others get the praise.
- For larger games, you have programmers dedicated just to 3D graphics, networking, audio, tools, scripting, physics and so on. Most of them are highly specialized and each of them can lead the game into a disaster. You'll only need advanced math skills if you're the graphics or physics guy. Well, or AI.
- Most games are fire-and-forget, apart from some bugfixes, unless it's one of the more successful games, which get an expansion pack or a sequel.
- Security is an important issue for online games, since there are much more annoying people trying to to put people off than there are for business applications, many of which are for (more or less) internal uses at the customer.
- You are expected to work much more than when writing business applications.
- To land a job for an AAA title, you need to have worked on at least three shipped AAA titles (no, no typo here, ever read some job descriptions at Blizzard or LucasArts? :P)

But here come the good things:

- You can pretend to work when you're playing games.
- And finally, programming games is fun. Priceless.

Comment: LOL. Trust me in Business development we get stuck with the too short deadlines that we weren't consulted on too.

Comment: "There is always a deadline to fear that is much too short. In business programming, you mostly make the deadline up for yourself."

Programmers work for managers who probably have unrealistic expectations, regardless if it is a game or business app.

Answer (score 6):

Business development is generally much more forgiving.

The reason is basically this; usually, people ARE PAID to use business software.  People PAY to use game software.

This may sound like it's not answering your question, but it really is.  When my boss says "use microsoft word for that document", they're providing the software, and I'm obligated to use micosoft word.  And so, when using it, when it decides to renumber all my chapter headings "just because" or a save to disk takes 30 seconds while it resolves OLE references (it's JUST ONE FREAKING EXCEL SPREADSHEET, for heaven's sake!), I just grit my teeth and remind myself I'm getting paid to do this.

Whereas, if I'm in a game, I'm expecting entertainment.  I'm expecting the experience to work properly, and smoothly, and cleanly, with no major stutters or problems.

Again, getting down to why this is an issue for programming; those loops and structures in the game had better be DAMN good to make sure there is no major slowdown, no stuttering in the game engine, nothing that makes the consumer who just spent X amount of his hard-earned dollars say "this is a piece of crap" and walk away.  With business software, you can get away with that sort of thing; in some ways, it's almost expected.  Again, look at the performance of Microsoft Word; if it were a game, it would be laughed out of existence.

I know I sound like I'm picking on Microsoft Word, and I generally am, because I find it to be hideous, but the point is true for so many pieces of software.  CAD software is another example.  Same basic things going on as in games, but in general it's slow and hard to work with without a lot of training.

The difference comes down to polish, and the level of polish that's expected.  Yes, there's generally more flexibility in business software than there is in games; but moreover and more importantly from a coding perspective, the code has GOT to work efficiently and cleanly in a game; business software is, generally, more forgiving of sloppy code.

In a business app, unoptimized and slow algorithms are generally accepted; and while they're never preferable, frequently the business decision gets made to add another feature instead of improving the performance.  But in games, performance IS a feature, and one which is make-or-break.

Comment: Complaining about Word makes me wonder if you've ever used any _real_ business software?  ;)  (SAP and Lotus Notes are only the two most obvious elephants in the room.)

Answer (score 5):

One big difference between business development and game development is the number of disciplines involved.  Most business software is created by a team of developers, who all have the same basic skillset.  In contrast, a game is created by a team of game designers, visual artists, 3d modelers, animators, musicians, and developers.

Comment: You're absolutely right, but I intended my question to focus on the programming aspect of it. I know that wasn't clear, so I'll edit my question a bit.

Answer (score 5):

One should have infinite loops, one shouldn't.

Comment: Actually, under modern GUI environments, both types of applications have infinite loops.

Answer (score 5):

> One should have infinite loops, one shouldn't. - Rich Bradshaw

Rich is right. Fundamentally, from a coding standpoint, a game loop creates a "frame" of action in which actions are taken based on the state of the game such as controller input, object collisions, etc. This loop repeats infinitely until some state of some game element or input tells it to stop or "quit." This approach keeps the CPU and graphics card pretty busy, hence the market for gamer machines with fast processors and even faster graphics cards.

Business applications do not have an active loop. Instead, they sit idle waiting for an event such as a click, a message from a web service client, an HTTP GET request, etc. Then they respond to the event.

Sure, gaming is generally more geometrically intensive than business applications, but that is not entirely true. Consider image editing, CAD and graphics tools. For many, these are business applications. But for the most part, a business application has to do with querying data, displaying that data, accepting user input, and modifying the data based on user input. In many cases, the business application does this across the network or even the Internet, but it's an apt nutshell.

The skillset and mindset of a business application developer and the game developer is often different. The game developer has a limited number of input constructs to consider in terms of creating a user experience with an unlimited choice of context or "world" if you will. The business developer is the opposite, with a limited set of potential contexts, usually the web page or the basic window, and an unlimited (or nearly so) set of input and data display combinations to create a user experience entirely different than the game developer sets out to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Good points about mathematics and integration of artists and other specialists in the team. In addition, I'd say that:

- Game development, to some extend, will be more hardware dependent. In many cases, games are built simultaneously to several platforms and consoles (not to mention cellphones), with different architectures. That is abstracted up to a certain extent, but developers cannot completely avoid this fact.
- Game development is often more performance sensitive, or at least the performance requirements are different. You're dealing with real-time experience, so a lot of time is spent optimizing those pesky fps.
- In many cases, game development does not care as much about reuse and maintainability. The game engine will probably be reused, but the application code base will probably not live to see v2.0. In the last stretch of a project, there is a lot of quick and dirty debugging going on. If it looks fine to the end user, there's no added value in making an elegant fix two days before the release.

Comment: Would you say the last point may be a little less relevant than it used to be now with even console games getting patches and downloadable content?

Comment: It is changing, but old habits die hard ;)

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from the goal - the goal of game development is to create entertaining product. It should be accurate to the extend that it looks good and runs smoothly. The goal of a business software solution is to model a work process. It should be a tool which works fast enough. A stable product, which executes absolutely accurately and secure the tasks it should do.

Since we target different goals, we use different approaches to build a game and a business software. Let's move to the requirements. For a game, the requirements are determined by the game designer. For a software product the business defines the process and the requirements. For a game the requirements are not final - shall we have small cartoon figures or real human models - this does not matter for the game engine for example. But for a software product, the requirements should be strictly followed and cleared to the maximum possible detail before development.

From the different requirements come different software design and development approach. For a game the performance and gameplay are critical and the qualiity of the graphics and sounds (for example) could be reduced just to be compatible with weaker hardware. Also the physical model could be simplified just to run smoother and improve the gameplay. For the business software everything should be exact and cutting features means that your product will not be as functional as designed anymore.

For a game, the security is not important - there is no critical customer data which should be saved. For a business software a good security system should be supplied - starting from data encryption (while saving on data storage or transferring through network) moving through backup system and mentioning (but not last) the compatibility with previous versions.

I could continue with other aspects but I guess this is already too much for one post...

Answer (score 2):

Business software (that isn't shrink-wrap software) can generally be much more poorly written but still considered a commercial success due to the bizarre disconnect between the quality of the product and saleability of the product.  Game software, on the other hand, has to actually be **good** to survive the marketplace.

The bar for quality in specialized business software is *generally* much lower.

Answer (score 1):

Business software has to be reliable, maintainable, consistent, not be too annoyingly slow,  and can build on lots of already written stuff, such as databases, controls, forms etc.

A games programmer often starts with a blank sheet - hardware reference manuals, some documentation about the hardware and usually thin vendor libraries around some advanced hardware that's completely different to the last job.

From this they have to build what you see - and make most of it work within a 20ms time period, reliably, and often within a ridiculously short time period, facing changing requirements and often a very hard deadline, working untold numbers of hours for a comparative pittance.

That's not to mention often having to master some fairly complex mathematics and physics....

Answer (score 0):

Performance is really the difference, from what I can tell.

Technologywise, games are usually Windows/C++ driven.

Answer (score 0):

Game programming has more in common with scientific programming. You are modeling behavioral systems and anticipating results based upon a limited set of input.